# JQuery hide elements with a class that starts with a string

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to hide elements that start with a specific class name.

I've added this to my code `$('[class^=webrtc_options_]').hide();` which doesn't seem to be picking up as expected.

HTML output looks like:

```
<div class="row webrtc_options_B">
```

Comment: The issue is because the `class` attribute in your example starts with `row`, not `webrtc_...`. It's possible to do what you require by filtering the list of elements, however it quickly becomes a hacky mess; which is why incremental class/id attributes are an anti-pattern. Just add another common class to all the elements, eg. `web_rtc_options` in this case, and select by that directly.

Comment: `$('div[class*=webrtc_options]').hide();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "*" operator like below. Because of the "row" class you are getting that issue when using start with operaotr.

```js
$("div[class*='webrtc_options_']").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row webrtc_options_B">ttttt</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to break down the class attribute into an array of individual classes:

```
$('div[class]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('class').split(' ').some(function(a) {
        return /^webrtc_options_/.test(a);
    });
})
.hide();
```

**DEMO**

```js
$('div[class]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('class').split(' ').some(function(a) {
        return /^webrtc_options_/.test(a);
    });
})
.hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row webrtc_options_B">ONE</div>
<div class="row xwebrtc_options_D">TWO</div>
<div class="webrtc_options_C row">THREE</div>
<div class="row">FOUR</div>
```